# Oomph Installation Error

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I want to install Eclipse using setup files, but I get this error:
Any ideas?
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some update sites from Eclipse was offline during your installation. Just try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using something like a proxy for your connection?
So you're offline / have bad connections or something like a proxy is blocking your connection.
Try the "Mirrors" option the page before the install process.